# How to scroll recyclerview based on another one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-swipe

I have two `recycleView` in the same layout and same `SwipeRefresher` one for normal result and another for *VIP* it's worked as well, but the *VIP* recycle come above the *result* recycle, and that gives me a wired result.

The screen show VIP while scrolling in the normal result.

How I can make two recycle with one scroll behavior?

My layout looks like this:-

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vipRecycleView"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/resultRecycleView"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The following image demonstrates my current statue.

[image]

Comment: It's normal that the resultRecyclerView match_parent in height ?

Comment: @Vodet yup what the problem in that ?

Comment: If I misunderstood, please correct. You want to say that when you scroll the upper recyclerview the lower recyclerview should also scroll with it. If so then you need to use tablayout and viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Try

> recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)

Main xml

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

recycler item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How it can set the recycle based on another ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedScrollView` and put both `RecyclerView`'s inside it

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/vipRecycleView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/resultRecycleView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: That's make me lost all behaviors on the recycleView, e.g `recycle.setOnScollListener(....)`